# Cronbach Alpha help

Tags: cronbachs-alpha

I had a test that I use to evaluate participants in a quality monitoring - I want to check the reliability of the tool.  I got the average of each category, can I use Cronbach alpha to check reliability, or is this exclusive to only scales.

Comment: My guess is that Cronbach's alpha can be used for this scale, but whether you can use it or not will depend on the data you collected. Can you provide more information about what you did? What kind of items does your scale have? Do items belong to subscales? Do you have the item-level responses for participants? What's the sample size? What software are you using for data analysis? Is there a reason you want Cronbach's alpha over other reliability measures?

Comment: THANK YOU FOR RESPONDING.

Comment: he tool I used was scored like such - Category 1 gave no intro 2 intro given but too long or short, etc. 3 and 4- Each week I evaluated 8 participants on 13 categories including the one above, I took the average of each category - I wanted to find the reliability of this tool - every example shows a Likert scale i.e I though 6, etc.  I do not want to use individual scores since I evaluated 35 participants over 12 weeks, I wanted to take the average of each categories and find the reliability of the tool using Cronbach alpha - is that doable?

Comment: also, I am using excel analysis.

Comment: Cronbach's alpha, like other measures of reliability, is related to items, so it needs to be calculated on the items themselves. I suspect that n = 35 may be fairly small for your case, and it sounds like your concern is the repeated measurement. If that's the case, then you may try computing the interclass correlation (ICC). The ICC could help you quantify how stable scores are over time, which is like test-retest reliability if there's no intervention being done on the sample that would change how they approach the scale

Comment: *intraclass, not interclass. My mistake